# ECS Fargate: Expected deployment circuit breaker rollback behaviour?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, circuit-breaker

For services deployed on ECS Fargate, we can choose to enable a deployment circuit breaker. We can also choose to enable rollback for that circuit breaker to [*"tell Amazon ECS to roll back to the last completed deployment upon a deployment failure"*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deployment-type-ecs.html).

**But how does this rollback differ from standard Fargate deployment behavior?**

My understanding of Fargate deployments *without a circuit breaker* is:

- A service is running healthily
- A new deployment is started, which keeps the existing service running
  while the new version is brought online
- Once the new version is running and passing healthchecks, the previous version starts connection draining and traffic is then routed to the new version
- If the new version does not start running as exepcted and does not pass healthchecks satisfactorily, the existing service stays as-is and traffic continues to go there.

So if we add a circuit breaker, and enable rollback - what happens?

I understand the failed deployment would stop trying after a certain number of attempts, but how does rollback take affect in this case? Without it, we already just leave the previous service running untouched, so enabling a rollback and triggering a deployment of the same service that is already running fine doesn't seem to make sense?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you are missing in your understanding of an ECS Fargate deployment.

1. Depending on the min and max healthy instances settings of the ECS service, ECS may delete all the old ECS tasks before starting new ECS tasks. What you describe is only the default behavior, but there are other possible behaviors.
2. ECS will continue trying to deploy the failed version over and over and over again, which could possibly incur lots of added costs to your AWS account, or could be affecting other AWS resources if the failure is failing database migration or something.

In either of the above scenarios, if you have circuit-breaker enabled, then after a period of failures ECS will stop trying to deploy the new version and go back to a known good state.

Comment: Thanks - but this doesn't address the *rollback* part. I know that circuit breaker will stop trying to deploy the new version - but what difference does enabling rollback make to this? - *circuit breaker* and *circuit breaker with rollback* are 2 different things

Comment: As I stated in point number 1, there are configuration settings in ECS that would Delete/Terminate the entire currently running tasks/containers before attempting to deploy the new version. In that case if it just stopped trying to deploy the new version then there would be NOTHING running, the app would be down. It has to roll-back by deploying the previous version of the container in order to get the app back up and running.